# Send Group Message with Twilio

Tags: sms, twilio

Is there a way to use twilio to send a message to a group thread? I don't want each recipient to have a separate thread with the twilio number sending the message.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Hey Jeff, I'm not quite sure what you mean here. SMS messages don't have the concept of a group thread. What is the result you are looking for here?

Comment: Hey Phil, it would be as if I sent a group message from my phone. Everyone who received the message could see the other numbers in the group. If anyone responded everyone would receive the text message.

Comment: Hey Jeff, I actually had no idea this worked on phones. My guess is that it requires a group of the same phones/OSes talking to each other to allow group SMSing to work. On that note, I don't believe Twilio can make that happen as you describe. One thing you could do is to set up one number that everyone in a group could message that would broadcast to the rest of the group.

Comment: Group messaging is a fairly common thing which works cross Oses too (atleast works between iOS and android). Ever found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Ricky from Twilio here.

You can't set it up as you described but we do have a blog post that outlines how to [build a group messaging app with Meteor and MongoDB](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/07/building-a-group-messaging-app-with-meteor-mongodb-and-twilio.html). This may get you, or anyone else who stumbles on this question, close.